# How to calculate the values at the points of a 10-point partition (Fourier Series)?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

We have the following periodic function.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+2,& -2<x<0 \newline
 2-2x, &  0<x<2
\end{cases}$$

We define the function and we make the plot

```
f[x_] := Which[-2 < x < 0, x + 2, 0 < x < 2, 2 - 2 x]
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]]

```
L = 4;
a[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
a[0] := (1/L)*Integrate[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
b[n_] := (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
F[x_, Nmax_] := 
 a[0] + Sum[a[n]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Nmax}]
p[Nmax_, a_] := 
 Plot[Evaluate[F[x, Nmax]], {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 200]
f[x_] := If[x > 0, 2 - 2 x, x + 2];
a[n]
a[0]
b[n]
Simplify[%, n \[Element] Integers]
p[5, 2]
p[10, 2]
p[15, 2]
p[20, 2]
```

With the following 4 partial sum plots
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now we want to define an error function $E(x)=|f(x)-S_N(x)|$ where $S_n$ for the partial sums of the Fourier series of the above function for N=7,14,20. I would like to calculate its values at the points of a 10-point partition of the base interval $[-L,L]$ using the Table and Tableform commands.

We have already defined $S_n$ above as

```
F[x_, Nmax_] := 
 a[0] + Sum[a[n]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Nmax}]
```

Now I have defined $E(x)$

```
e[x_, Nmax_] := Abs[f[x] - F[x, Nmax]]
```

But I think I miss something. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for Fourier series, you are supposed to use MSE (mean square error) to compare the performance of the approximation given by Fourier series against the real function. This I think is the common way to measure error with Fourier series.

The formula is

[image]

```
Integrate[Abs[f[x] - F[x, 10]]^2, {x, -L/2, L/2}];
Sqrt[%] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[Abs[f[x] - F[x, 20]]^2, {x, -L/2, L/2}];
Sqrt[%] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Integrate[Abs[f[x] - F[x, 50]]^2, {x, -L/2, L/2}];
 Sqrt[%] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that mean square error goes down as more terms are added. Most of the error comes due to Gibbs. In theory, there will always be such an error at the ends, and this Gibbs error can't be eliminated no matter how many terms are used.

**Update**

If the question is asking to find Fourier series at specific x points of partition 10, then one way is (note the definition of f(x) is changed a little below from the question in order to include the end points and zero.

```
L = 4;
f[x_] := Which[-2 <= x <= 0, x + 2, 0 < x <= 2, 2 - 2 x]
a[n_] = (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
a[0] = (1/L)*Integrate[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
b[n_] = (2/L)*Integrate[f[x]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
F[x_, Nmax_] := 
 a[0] + Sum[a[n]*Cos[2 n*Pi*x/L] + b[n]*Sin[2 n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Nmax}]

(*divide the period into 10 equal intervals*)
partitions = Subdivide[-L/2, L/2, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*evaluate F.S. approximation at each one of these points *)
Map[(F[x, 7] /. x -> #) &, partitions] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Map[(F[x, 10] /. x -> #) &, partitions] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Map[(F[x, 100] /. x -> #) &, partitions] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 (*Compare to actual f(x)*)
 Map[f[#] &, partitions] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that at end points the error is largest due to Gibbs but inside, the error goes down. This is why MSE is needed to calculate the error over the whole interval.

**Update**

> is it possible to write it with Table or TableForm

One way could be (for 10 partitions, using 7 number of terms)

```
partitions = Subdivide[-L/2, L/2, 10];
data = Table[z = partitions[[n]]; {z, N@F[z, 7], N[f[z]]}, {n, 1, 
    Length[partitions]}];
TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {None, {"x value", "F(x)", " f(x)"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To add error column  (pointwise error, not MSE error)

```
data = Table[z = partitions[[n]]; 
   error = Abs[N[F[z, 7] - f[z]]]; {z, N@F[z, 7], N[f[z]], error}, {n,
     1, Length[partitions]}];
TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"x value", "F(x)", " f(x)", "point error"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the above as needed.

Comment: You chose $N=10,20,50$ to calculate the values of the points of a 10-point partition on the interval $[-L/2,L/2]$. Correct?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos  I just gave examples of different N. You can choose N=10 for your needs. But the above is the formula. Only the first uses N=10 (with MSE error of .27), the others use a different N ofcourse. I just wanted to show the MSE goes down as N increases. You need to integrate over one period. I assumed you are asking how to find/calculate the error in approximation.

Comment: My exercise asks for the partial sums of the Fourier series of the above function for $N=7,14,20$. I got it now. So I have to calculate the value for each $N$. The question that confuses me is "calculate its values at the points of a 10-point partition of the base interval $[−,]$ using the Table and Tableform commands".

Comment: **calculate its values at the points of a 10-point partition** So you want the value of fApprximation(x,N)? It seems the question is asking to evaluate the F.S. at specific x points? In this case you can divide the period into 10 partitions and just evaluate F.S. at each one of these points using   `F[x,10]/.x->point` ? I can't help with the interpretation of the question much, but that is what it sound it is asking. May be you can ask another student in the class or the teacher for clarification? I thought you are asking for error estimate, since that is what you wrote last thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos fyi, added partition also.

Comment: Instead of the command Map is it possible to write it with Table or TableForm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142190/discussion-between-athanasios-paraskevopoulos-and-nasser).

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos fyi, added tableform

Comment: Thank you again for all the help